# How to covert mysql to excel file using php?

Tags: mysql, excel

I am just wondering what's the most efficient way to export mysql data to excel file using PHP. I have been searching on web but not sure what the best way is. Any thoughts? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this PHPExcel - OpenXML Api: http://www.phpexcel.net

I never tested that, but the feature list says that it can export data to

- Excel 2007 (spreadsheetML)
- BIFF8 (Excel 97 and higher)
- PHPExcel Serialized Spreadsheet
- CSV (Comma Separated Values)
- HTML
- PDF

Good luck!